# Why is SQLite pragma foreign_keys not persistent across DB connections?

Tags: c, sqlite

I found myself debugging why an  `ON DELETE CASCADE` was not working, until realizing that foreign keys must be enabled for *every* database connection, with `PRAGMA foreign_keys = <boolean>;` (ref: https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys).

From a development point of view, I feel it is complex to manage when to enable/disable SQLite foreign keys. To be on the safe side, I would rather hook this statement with `ON`, for every connection. But then I wonder what is the actual penalty or reason for not having such setting persistent across DB connections.

So my questions are:

1. Why didn't SQLite choose to have foreign keys enabled by default?
2. Assuming 1. has good reasons, why didn't SQLite choose to have this setting persistent at database file or table level, instead of being per connection?
3. Can you give an idea of how big a penalty it is to use foreign keys enabled for operations that do not require them?

If it matters, I'm using the C implementation of SQLite, version 3.22.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite supports foreign key constraints since [version 3.6.19 (2009-10-14)](https://sqlite.org/releaselog/3_6_19.html).

For your 1st question, from [Enabling Foreign Key Support](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html):

> Foreign key constraints are disabled by default (**for backwards
> compatibility**), so must be enabled separately for each database
> connection. (Note, however, that future releases of SQLite might
> change so that foreign key constraints enabled by default. Careful
> developers will not make any assumptions about whether or not foreign
> keys are enabled by default but will instead enable or disable them as
> necessary.)

As for your other questions, you may read [SQLite Forum / Why is foreign key support based on the connection?](https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/f99d13712f) to get an idea of how others deal with this feature/problem.
The interesting part in this thread, which you can also find in [Compile-time Options](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#overview) is that you can compile the core library with the compile time constant `SQLITE_DEFAULT_FOREIGN_KEYS` set to `1` (= `ON`) and get your own flavor of SQLite.

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the exact same question on SQLite forum. Sounds like the right answer. I also found [this scenario](https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/c5dc50f61b?t=h) particularly suitable to justify this flag per connection: _"If you have a bulk update that's already filtering by the referenced table, extra checks of the foreign key constraints are needless overhead."_ . This allows higher performance.